# I can`t access properties of model using custom model manager

Tags: python, django-models

i am write custom model manager for customer model here is my model

```
class CustomerMenager(models.Manager):
    def getCutomerCountry(self):
        return self.filter(country__exact='India')


class Customer(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    mymanager = CustomerMenager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstName
```

and my view as

```
def customerView(request):
    custmr = CustomerForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        custmr = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        if custmr.is_valid():
              custmr.save()
            

    c = Customer.mymanager.getCutomerCountry()
    print(c)
    return render(request,'customer.html',{'customer':custmr,'cust':c})
```

when above code execute i get following object

```
 Django version 3.1.2, using settings 'DjangoTuts.settings'
 Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 
 Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
 <QuerySet [<Customer: amit>]>
```

but when i am accensing this object in template like this
cust.firstName it gives me error that

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'firstName'
```

i am not geting why this happened. please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `getCutomerCountry` is returning a `QuerySet` object, not a `Customer` object.

to solve this issue, you can either make `getCutomerCountry` return the first object, like the following:

```
...
    def getCutomerCountry(self):
        return self.filter(country__exact='India').first()
```

or in your view code, get the first `Customer` from the `QuerySet`, like the following:

```
def customerView(request):
    ...        
    c = Customer.mymanager.getCutomerCountry().first()
    ...
```

this will resolve the error your are seeing.